# SOAP Fault: "User Password required for Service Operation CI_GAX_TEAM_MEMBER_CI_G"

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I'm currently working on a web service that is failing with the following SOAP error:

> Additional information: The content type text/html of the response
>   message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 638
>   bytes of the response were: '

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
 <faultstring>null</faultstring>
 <detail>
     <IBResponse type="error">
         <DefaultTitle>Integration Broker Response</DefaultTitle>
         <StatusCode>20</StatusCode>
         <MessageID>535</MessageID>
         <DefaultMessage><![CDATA[User Password required for Service Operation CI_GAX_TEAM_MEMBER_CI_G. (158,535)]]></DefaultMessage>
         <MessageParameters>
             <Parameter><![CDATA[CI_GAX_TEAM_MEMBER_CI_G]]></Parameter>
         </MessageParameters>
     </IBResponse>
 </detail>
 </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'."
```

the web service was originally in http but for security reasons we had to switch it to https. The main part of this being `CDATA[User Password required for Service Operation CI_GAX_TEAM_MEMBER_CI_G. (158,535)`, I don't think this is a password issue I just think it might be having a problem somewhere with security setup in a config file or something. I can get past the initial part where it prompts me to enter in an ID, which means it's connecting via https but it seems there may be a cert issue here with this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Apologies but it is quite difficult to understand the operating environment you are working in from your description.

Comment: Visual Studio/C#, this a C# application, with a web service and a client side

Comment: A service returned you a SOAP Fault. I don't know why it got turned into HTML, but it's pretty clear what it says (_once you format the XML correctly_).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of receiving any valid response message from server (in your case, a valid soap message,it could be a soap fault too), you are receiving a webpage (text/html).

Usually it happens in case of, authentication failure/ authorization/ access denied etc.

As you mentioned, http to https protocol change in your service, so definitely it should be authentication issue.

Best thing in this scenario would be, to get yourself familiar with tools like soapui and try to establish connection with your web service using it, then change your existing client accordingly.

It is easier to  provide authentication/ certificates etc in these tools rater than trying directly in your client code. And also you can see the logs and error details clearly.